# Oauth2 Redirect when User Clicks Deny

Tags: box-api

The new Oauth2 authorization process seems to work very well. It took a little time to change my class methods to handle it and the other changes to the API, but I have everything working smoothly now.  One small problem I haven't figured out yet is how to pick up the redirect request when the user clicks "Deny" on the 2nd part of the login process.  I get the redirect fine when "Allow" is clicked, but I get nothing at all on "Deny."  My callback URL is something like `ht-btz://com.cloud` so according to the documentation, I'm supposed to get something like this:

`ht-btz://com.cloud??error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+access+to+your+application`

I've tried it with a custom, Python-wrapped IE browser that can monitor redirection, and with a custom local URL protocol handler, and neither gets any request to the callback uri. But both pick up exactly what the documentation says on the approval click.

It's not really a showstopper, since the "Deny" click stops everything anyway.  But it would be better to handle things gracefully with the callback request.  So is this is bug, or am I missing something?

thanks

Mike

Comment: Hm, I'm seeing the redirect when I test it against a regular http:// site. It might have something to do with the custom protocol.

Comment: Your site won't allow an http callback, so I tried an https url, and still nothing.

Comment: Sean, after trying some more, I got https to work for both Accept and Deny.  But it's still a no-go on the Deny with a custom protocol.

Comment: Oops, yeah I meant https originally. I'm seeing similarly odd behavior with a custom protocol. We're looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug on Box's end with non-HTTPS protocols. We're working on a fix and should have it out sometime this week.

Comment: Thanks Sean. The other api changes seem to be working just fine. Thanks for the good work.